# How can I parse a local JSON file from assets folder into a Jetpack Compose LazyColumn?

Tags: android, json, android-jetpack-compose

How can I parse a local JSON file from assets folder into data class than to Jetpack Compose List (`LazyColumn`)?
Have a list of products in JSON format.
I've created a resource directory, import the JSON file.

Want to convert it to a list a display it in composable `LazyColumn`

Answer (score 2):

The solution consists of several steps:

1. Access your assets by calling `assets` somewhere in your `Activity`
2. Read the data from the file by using a useful extension function on the `assets`

```kotlin
private fun AssetManager.readAssetsFile(fileName: String): String = open(fileName).bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
```

2. Convert the received string to a concrete type by using any Serialization/Deserialization library like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi). For example, your type could be `List<YourItemType>` (depends on how it's stored in the file)
3. Iterate over the items you've got and add them to a `LazyColumn`

Comment: 2. i'm reading the file assets.readAssetsFile("users.json")

Comment: Trying the following val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
        val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<User> = moshi.adapter(User::class.java)
        val data = AssetManager.open("users.json").bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
        jsonAdapter.fromJson(data)